# javascript tables not being placed inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I have this HTML file which has this div and I want the javascript files I am calling which creates some tables. The tables are being created outside the div. How can I get the tables created inside the div?

here is my html file:

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}

{%block body%}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">

{%block content%}


    <div class="jumbotron text-center">

        <!-- TABLE DATA FOR TABLE1 -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            var tableData = {{ table1|safe }}
        </script>
        <script src="../static/merit_table.js"></script>

        <!-- TABLE DATA FOR TABLE2 -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tableData = {{ table2|safe }}
        </script>
        <script src="../static/merit_table.js"></script>

        <!-- TABLE DATA FOR TABLE3 -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tableData = {{ table3|safe }}
        </script>
        <script src="../static/merit_table.js"></script>

    </div>

{%endblock%}

{%endblock%}
```

here is my css file:

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* or margin: 0 auto 0 auto */
}

th, td {
    width: 250px;
    font-size : 130%;

}
```

here is my javascript file:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');


for (var key in tableData) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode(key);
    var text2 = document.createTextNode(tableData[key]);

    td1.appendChild(text1);
    td2.appendChild(text2);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the table to the document body rather than to the div. Try giving your div an id and then appending to that id instead of to the body. Something like:

html line 10: `<div class="jumbotron text-center" id="table-div">`

JS last line: `document.getElementByID("table-div").appendChild(table);`

Comment: looks like im closer now, but I get the following error in the js file "TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function"

Comment: Also the error is coming from this line in the js file : document.getElementByID("table-div").appendChild(table);

Comment: Got it. The casting was a little different for me its "document.getElementById("table-div").appendChild(table);" and not "document.getElementByID("table-div").appendChild(table);"